# Can multiple Excel worksheets be treated like a database and combine records according to a primary key?

Tags: excel

I have two Excel files: one that contains respondents' answers to a survey and a second with respondents' school record information.  The two files have one like column (student ID).  Is there a way to combine the records so that the student records are connected to survey responses?

Comment: Short answer Yes. You can do this using VBA or perhaps using Excel functions. Hence, it would be advisable if you can point out your exact issue along with your efforts to solve it so that SO users can help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Vlookup() or an Index/Match combination to look up data from one file and show it in the other.

Vlookup can only return information that is to the right of the key column. Using Index/Match the order of the columns does not matter.

If you need a concrete formula, please edit your question and provide the structure of your files and/or a data sample for both files.